# I am passing parametes in xml file still system is taking value as param-val-not-found

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am using parameter annotation , I have passed values in Alltext.xmls file , But system is not identifying the value and it is taking value as "param-value-not-found".

Alltest.java class

```
public class AllTest {

    @Parameters({ "username1", "password1" })
    @Test(priority = 1, groups = { "PositiveTest", "smokeTests" })
    public void positiveloginTest(String username1, String password1) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Start login test");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String url = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login";
        driver.get(url);
        System.out.println("Page is opened");

        // Locators

        WebElement username2 = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        username2.sendKeys(username1);

        WebElement password2 = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        password2.sendKeys(password1);

        WebElement loginbutton = driver.findElement(By.className("radius"));
        loginbutton.click();
}
```

Alltest.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="AllTest" verbose="1">

    <test name="PositiveTest">
        <parameter name="username1" value="tomsmith" />
        <parameter name="password1" value="SuperSecretPassword!" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="PositiveTests"></include>
            </run>

        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.herokuapp.theinternet.AllTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **`typo`** in group name

Group name `PositiveTest` given in test annotation while `PositiveTests` used in testng.xml file. remove extra `s` from group name under xml file

Comment: I have removed group annotation , when I run the AllTest.java , System is thronging that error ,  when i run the AllTest.xmls fine , there was no error system is taking the parameters correctly

Comment: obviously you will get the error if run `AllTest.java` it require parameter value which is you passing from xml. else from where you will get the parameter value ?

Comment: you should mark @Optional to make it work if parameters are optional `public void positiveloginTest(@Optional String username1, @Optional String password1) {`

Comment: Sure , it is usefull .Thanks a lot